# Mysql slow query log not tally with mysqladmin

Tags: mysql, query

I have enabled my slow query log. So I saw the query which was taking some time then I did some indexing it improve and my slow query log is not being showing any more queies. But when I run this command

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
Enter password:
Uptime: 9395  Threads: 2  Questions: 474976  Slow queries: 13  Opens: 99  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 54  Queries per second avg: 50.556
```

It is showing me slow queries:13. What does the thread n questions means here?

Here is how I set `my.cnf` file.

```
    [mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
log_warnings = 2
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is since the last restart of the mysql service. If it is not growing then you are good

Comment: ok thx I was worried I thought is the current one. What does uptime and thread tell here? The queries-per-second is how many queries process in one second also since last start is it?

Comment: Good post about it: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?12,86570,86570

Comment: thx for link. I would like to share something with you I have a java application where I create one single database connection. Then I have like 20 different threads running which all share the single connection. Will that be a good architecture or open each different connection for each thread?

Comment: Is it likea connection pooling ? If yes, we use this for a long time and helps a lot, very performance effective solution

Comment: no is not a connection pooling just one single connection created and being share by multiple thread but I head that is dangerous if we are using transaction is it?

Comment: Check this nice article about transaction isolation http://www.ovaistariq.net/597/understanding-innodb-transaction-isolation-levels/

Comment: based on your experience do you think this single connection will pose as a dangerous mechanism in future?

Comment: Post your my.cnf as an update to your post

Comment: I have posted my full my.cnf. Any comments on it?

Comment: According to your configuration, I strongly recommend to read that documentation about the transaction isolation

Comment: I have read it but it does indicate about isolation but there is nothing about connection sharing so here is where I am lost and in a dilema which route to choose?